# how do I detect windows system information in c++

Tags: c++, windows, graphics, audio, system

I'm writing a windows game, but in order to run it has to meet certain requirements. How do I detect the system requirements of the computer?

I only need to read the information, such as RAM, CPU, Graphics hardware, and sound hardware.

The msdn website is a maze, and I have no clue where to look this up.

Comment: I wouldn't bother detecting things like this. Those old game installers which say "warning, you have -15939397846434292" MB of disk space left are really annoying!

Answer (score 3):

Polling the graphics hardware should be done through Direct3D. [__cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh%28VS.80%29.aspx) is an intrinsic in Visual Studio.

[GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) will do for RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32/browse_thread/thread/5468a220cf78a89b/56bcebf50119103d?pli=1):
 * GetSystemInfo - Processor info
 * GetVersionEx- osversion/service pack
 * GlobalMemoryStatusEx- Memory status